# readline's rl_parse_and_bind causes crash

Tags: readline, segmentation-fault

I am using Ubuntu 18.04.5.  This very simple program segfaults on the invocation of `rl_parse_and_bind`.  Can anyone help me?

```
// Build with cc read.c -o read -lreadline

#include <readline/readline.h> // apt install libreadline-dev

int main() {
    rl_parse_and_bind("\"C-b\":history-search-backward");
    char *input = readline("Input: ");
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because the `readline` library will **actively modify** that string using `strtok`, and the string you passed *is a constant*. Trying to write to it will result in a segmentation fault.

Try:

```
char *copy = strdup("\"C-b\":history-search-backward");
rl_parse_and_bind(copy);
// free(copy); copy = NULL; // This to tidy up things
```

The copy, being writeable, will work.

Comment: Thank you.  How did you know about this?

Comment: I did not know, but I suspected: I had this happen to me with other functions. To really be sure I would have used valgrind, but it was not necessary, copy turned out to have been modified just as I expected.